# Problems updating android object storage

Tags: android, object

I have an app where when a `listfragment` is loaded, it loads my *custom list adapter* which usually works, but I am just now trying to implement *object storage* so that even when the app is closed and reopened, the objects persist at all times, and are only ever deleted when the user manually deletes them.

I am trying to implement it here but with this method, when the `listfragment` is loaded there is a 'loading icon' in the center of the screen that doesnt go away. I found out through log outputs that it is because the try block is never entered, the code right before it is but the code in the try block isn't, why would this be?

```
public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment{ 
    OnListSelectedListener mCallback;
    public ObjectStorage mainObjectList = new ObjectStorage();  //creates the list of objects
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;


    // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
    public interface OnListSelectedListener {
        /** Called by ListFragment when a list item is selected */
        public void onItemSelected(int position, String schedulename, String[] ampm, boolean[] days, int[] times, boolean vibrate);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        updateStorage();
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(mPrefs.getString("myobject", "").getBytes());
        ObjectInputStream in;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(byteArray);
            ObjectStorage updatedStorageList = (ObjectStorage) in.readObject();
            CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), 
                    R.layout.listview_item_row, updatedStorageList);
            //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, arraylist));
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void updateStorage()
    {
        getActivity();//used for MODE_PRIVATE

        //store object list into android system
        mPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
        ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(arrayOutputStream);
            out.writeObject(mainObjectList);
            out.close();
            arrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ed.putString("myobject", arrayOutputStream.toString());
        ed.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If setListAdapter is in try catch block, and a exception is raised then setListAdapter will never perform the bind to fragment. You can call setListAdapter outside of try catch block with a empty list,  and then you can add the objects manually inside the try catch method.

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ObjectStorage emptyList = new ObjectStorage(); // or some like new ArrayList<Object>();
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, emptyList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
    updateStorage();
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(mPrefs.getString("myobject", "").getBytes());
    ObjectInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(byteArray);
        ObjectStorage updatedStorageList = (ObjectStorage) in.readObject();

        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, arraylist));
        adapter.addAll(updatedStorageList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```